# first name and last name initial only on Database query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi can you help me in my problem?

I want to create a Profile Name which only read like this `Sergio E.` not this `Sergio Encabo`

Here is the query I have

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, COUNT(b.id) AS bids, p.slug, p.`description`, p.budget AS budget, p.`isFeatured`, p.`slug`, u.`profileLink`, u.`profilePhoto`, CONCAT_WS(' ', u.firstName , u.lastName ) AS fullName 
FROM tbl_projects AS p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u ON p.userId = u.userId 
LEFT JOIN tbl_bids AS b ON p.`id` = b.`projectId` 
WHERE p.`isActive` = 'y' AND u.`isActive` = 'y' AND p.`jobStatus` = 'open' AND p.userId=? 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Do you know any MySQL function that can return the first character of a string?

Comment: Have you tried LEFT(CustomerName, 1) , '.' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the first char on left for lastname

but you should not use left joined  tables columns  in where condition this work as inner join
add these condition to on clause

```
    $qry = "SELECT p.id
        , p.title
        , COUNT(b.id) AS bids
        , p.slug
        , p.`description`
        , p.budget AS budget
        , p.`isFeatured`
        , p.`slug`
        , u.`profileLink`
        , u.`profilePhoto`
        , CONCAT( u.firstName ,' ', left(u.lastName,1), '.' ) AS fullName 
        FROM tbl_projects AS p 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u ON p.userId = u.userId   AND u.`isActive` = 'y' 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_bids AS b ON p.`id` = b.`projectId`
        WHERE p.`isActive` = 'y' 
        AND p.`jobStatus` = 'open' 
         AND p.userId=? 
         GROUP BY p.id 
         ORDER BY p.`id` DESC  ";
```

Comment: @SergioEncabo  the rescue was rather easy